# Is there a workaround to dereference a list element that's the name of an undefined symbol, and iteratively assign values to the symbols in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, mapthread

The title mostly covers what I would like to do. The image below shows in some situations it *is* possible dereference an element in a list using Evaluate to assign a value:

```
a[[0]]
   (*Symbol*)
vars = {a, b, c}
Evaluate[vars[[1]]] = 1
{a[[0]], a}
   (*{Integer, 1}*)
```

However, trying to do this for several items in a list with an explicit pure function map doesn't fair as well (likely because "The expression #1 cannot be used as a part specification"):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
Evaluate[vars[[#]]] = # & /@ Range[3]
   (*Part::pkspec1: The expression #1 cannot be used as a part specification. >>*)
   (*Set::setps: {a,b,c} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>*)
   (* ... compared to below which works ... *)
Evaluate[vars[[#]]] == # & /@ Range[3]
   (*{a == 1, b == 2, c == 3}*)
```

Ideally I'd like to use MapThread for this particular task, but that doesn't appear to work either:

```
MapThread[Evaluate[[#1]] = #2 &, {vars, {1, 2, 3}}]
   (* Set::pkspec1: The expression #1 cannot be used as a part specification. >> *)
```

Any tips or workarounds on how to pull something like this off?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Post the code so that anyone can  easy to test it.

Comment: Syntax coloring indicates you need parentheses.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks for that, I noticed the syntax error coloring myself, but I've tried (...), {...}, and [...] around the # in `vars[[#]]` and different attempts at escaping the result, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Evaluate@vars[[#]] = #) & /@ Range[3]
```

Comment: Thanks @asd1dsa is there a reason you prefer prefix form over say `(Evaluate[vars[[#]]] = #) & /@ Range[3]`? Either way it worked, much appreciated!

Comment: @DustinDarcy I use prefix for readability. Triple nested `[ ]` is hard to read, isn't it? If you are not familiar with the precedence, paratheses are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `MapThread`, I recommend `Do` for the more general case where the values are also taken from a list. Like so:

```
Clear[a, b, c]
vars = {a, b, c};
vals = {27, 16, 32};
Do[Evaluate[vars[[i]]] = vals[[i]], {i, Length @ vars}];
vars
```

> ```
> {27, 16, 32}
> ```